# Export transactions require a customer name and address - Stripe Error

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I'm using stripe SDK for creating customers & charge to a customer using API, but getting an error with **"Fatal error: Uncaught (Status 400) (Request req_ZyqUtykjUcOqrU) As per Indian regulations, export transactions require a customer name and address. More info here: https://stripe.com/docs/india-exports thrown in /opt/lampp/htdocs/stripe/lib/Exception/ApiErrorException.php on line 38"**

My code is like below:

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey(STRIPE_API_KEY); 


$customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array( 
        'name' => 'test',
        'description' => 'test description',        
        'email' => $email, 
        'source'  => $token 
));
$orderID = strtoupper(str_replace('.','',uniqid('', true))); 

$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array( 
        'customer' => $customer->id, 
        //'source' => 'rtest',
        'amount'   => $itemPrice, 
        'currency' => $currency, 
        'description' => $itemName, 
        'metadata' => array( 
            'order_id' => $orderID 
        ) 
    ));
```

Comment: So did you try to provide address to API? Error message does not look enigmatic to me.

Comment: @MaximSagaydachny - Thanks man for your time, but it's resolved with **Rajdip Chauhan's** solution below.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As your error suggested you need to pass address object in stripe customer create API as per below example

```
$customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
    'name' => 'test',
    'description' => 'test description',
    'email' => $email,
    'source' => $token,
    "address" => ["city" => $city, "country" => $country, "line1" => $address, "line2" => "", "postal_code" => $zipCode, "state" => $state]
));
```

Note: line1 is required in address object

Comment: where is this → '$address'?

Comment: @beginner115 it's an array.
Reference: https://stripe.com/docs/india-exports#export-of-services

Comment: How to add the test address?

Answer (score 10):

change the currency to INR from USD

i was working on Node & React this helps me

**currency: 'INR'**

this will fix your problem probably.

Comment: stripe is not for INR only please guide someone in correct direction

Comment: sir, for indian cutomer stripe developer had made some changes so you can credit the user in term of INR and build your own logic to convert into other currency hope this will help you.

Comment: Worked for me as well.

Answer (score 2):

Even I was facing the same issue.

Just make sure you are putting the same currency.

For example:
if you have mentioned india as your country then put "inr" else "usd"
use this for your reference:

```
    customer=stripe.Customer.create(
        email=request.POST["email"],
        name=request.POST["nickname"],
        source=request.POST["stripeToken"],
        )
        customer=stripe.Customer.modify(
            customer.id,
            address={"city":"mumbai","country":"india","line1":"unr","line2":"thane","postal_code":"421005","state":"maharashtra"},
        )
        charge=stripe.Charge.create(
        customer=customer,
        amount=500,
        currency='inr',
        description="payment"
        )
```

Comment: Please use \`\` to indicate code, for example \`customer=stripe.Customer...\`, which then displays as `customer=stripe.Customer...`   If you have a block of code, then separate the code with at least one empty line, and indent the code by 4 spaces.

Answer (score 1):

i had this issue in stripe nodejs i fixed it by passing address

```
const stripeAddress: Stripe.AddressParam = {
        line1: userAddress.street1,
        line2: userAddress.street2,
        city: userAddress.city,
        country: userAddress.country,
        postal_code: userAddress.zip,
        state: userAddress.state,
      };




 const stripeCustomer: Stripe.Customer = await this.stripe.customers.create(
    {
      name: userData.name,
      description: userData.description,
      email: userData.email,
      phone: userData.phoneNumber,
      address: stripeAddress,
    }
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete working solution:

```
<?php 
require('config2.php');

$token = $_POST['stripeToken'];

$customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
    'name' => 'test',
    'description' => 'test description',
    'email' => 'murali@jytra.com',
    'source' => $token,
    "address" => ["city" => "hyd", "country" => "india", "line1" => "adsafd werew", "postal_code" => "500090", "state" => "telangana"]
));


$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array( 
        'customer' => $customer->id, 
        'amount'   => '100', 
        'currency' => 'inr', 
        'description' => "TrueCAD 2021 Premium", 
    )); 


echo "<pre>";
print_r($charge);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**i had this issue with stripe (MERN project). Just make sure you are putting description and shipping details**

```
const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
    amount: 100, // subunits of currency
    currency: "usd",
    description: "for amazon-clone project",
    shipping: {
      name: "Random singh",
      address: {
        line1: "510 Townsend St",
        postal_code: "98140",
        city: "San Francisco",
        state: "CA",
        country: "US",
      },
    },
});
```