# com.stripe.exception.InvalidRequestException: As per Indian regulations, export transactions require a customer name and address. in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, stripe-payments

i integrated stripe in my spring boot project

```
    @PostMapping("/create-charge")
     public @ResponseBody Response createCharge(String email, String token) {
            if (token == null) {
                return new Response(false, "Stripe payment token is missing. Please, try again later.");
            }
            String chargeId = stripeService.createCharge(email, token, 999); //$9.99 USD
            if (chargeId == null) {
                return new Response(false, "An error occurred while trying to create a charge.");
            }

            return new Response(true, "Success! Your charge id is " + chargeId);
        }
```

My Service

```
public String createCharge(String email, String token, int amount) {
        String id = null;
        try {
            Stripe.apiKey = API_SECRET_KEY;
            Map<String, Object> chargeParams = new HashMap<>();
            chargeParams.put("amount", amount);
            chargeParams.put("currency", "usd");
            chargeParams.put("description", "Charge for " + email);
            chargeParams.put("source", token); // ^ obtained with Stripe.js

            //create a charge
            Charge charge = Charge.create(chargeParams);
            id = charge.getId();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return id;
    }
```

i am getting exception
com.stripe.exception.InvalidRequestException: As per Indian regulations, export transactions require a customer name and address. More info here: https://stripe.com/docs/india-exports
How should i pass the address in request?
I tried to pass the address like this

```
 Stripe.apiKey = API_SECRET_KEY;
            Map<String, Object> chargeParams = new HashMap<>();
            chargeParams.put("amount", amount);
            chargeParams.put("currency", "usd");
            chargeParams.put("description", "Charge for " + email);
            chargeParams.put("source", token); // ^ obtained with Stripe.js
            Map<String, Object> customerParams = new HashMap<>();
            Map<String, String> addressParams = new HashMap<>();
            customerParams.put("description", "Customer for " + email);
            customerParams.put("email", email);
            customerParams.put("address", addressParams);
            addressParams.put("city", "varanasi");
            addressParams.put("country", "india");

            customerParams.put("source", token); // ^ obtained with Stripe.js
            //create a new customer
            Customer customer = Customer.create(customerParams);
            chargeParams.put("customer", customer.getId());

            //create a charge
            Charge charge = Charge.create(chargeParams);
            id = charge.getId();
```

but now getting exception
com.stripe.exception.InvalidRequestException: Customer cus_JIMd90oUI9V8e6 does not have a linked source with ID tok_1Iflu8AuNrJFnosEZI2huyYo.; code: missing

when i changed the currency to inr the issue is fixed but i dont want to change the currency

Comment: Error clearly saying, you need to send the customer name and address, are you sending them in your request?

Comment: No how to send address in request?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59282024/export-transactions-require-a-customer-name-and-address-stripe-error) answer your question?

Comment: can you convert the code in java?

Comment: If you follow the one of the strip documentation link in the answer, they have already mentioned code for almost every language out there. Here is the [link](https://stripe.com/docs/india-accept-international-payments#export-of-services)

Comment: but in the example of java code is very confusing
"CustomerCreateParams" dont know from where they use this class and also what will the flow for recieving payment 1- Create customer and the Charge

Comment: What is `Charge` class in your code?

Comment: it is in stripe package for charging the amount
 Map<String, Object> customerParams = new HashMap<>();
            Map<String, String> addressParams = new HashMap<>();
            customerParams.put("description", "Customer for " + email);
            customerParams.put("email", email);
            customerParams.put("address", addressParams);
            addressParams.put("country", "india");
            customerParams.put("source", token);
            Customer customer = Customer.create(customerParams);
            chargeParams.put("customer", customer.getId());

Comment: com.stripe.exception.InvalidRequestException: Customer cus_JIMd90oUI9V8e6 does not have a linked source with ID tok_1Iflu8AuNrJFnosEZI2huyYo.; code: missing
getting this exception

Comment: I think, you first read the documentation carefully,  the code or example you are following is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

I received this exception as well while creating charge using Stripe API.

I'm not much familiar with Java but assuming that there's no other error.

Try this: **change** the **currency** from **USD** to **INR**.

This worked for me, so hopefully will work for you as well.